# ruby: mysql2 select statement with null

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I try to select all rows with ruby where the field is null. Either I get zero results or the statement is invalid. So far I tried:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM names where name is null;")
db.query("SELECT * FROM names where name is nil;")
db.query("SELECT * FROM names where name is #{null};")
db.query("SELECT * FROM names where name is #{nil};")
```

How should the select statement be?

i use ruby and mysql2 gem

Comment: Replace `#select_stmt` with `#query` .. like `db.query("SELECT * FROM names where name is null;")`

Comment: i forget to say i use ruby and the mysql2 gem. select_stmt should be query. update: "Select * from names where names is null;" worked suddenly

Comment: We can see that from the tags - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: The first statement is correct. Have you tried that same statement in the MySQL prompt to see if you get a different result?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * from 'names' WHERE 'name' IS NULL`

This is what works in plain MySQL, seeing now that you use ruby this might not help you.